# Android onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, video-recording

I am stuck in a situation, which is described as follows in terms of my app chart flow :

Suppose I am on Activity A, Here at the onclick of a button I pick the images from the gallery and after picking, I am moving to the Activity B ( it comes internally from onActivity result - by passing the Intent ). Now here when I am on Activity B and click on a Button, there is a call to the Custom Video maker. Here I capture a video for 10 secs and then I finished ( Activity C) using

```
C.this.finish();
```

Now as per the Android Activity Flow I SHOULD MOVE BACK TO THE ACTIVITY B, But in my case I am getting one black Screen for few seconds and then getting Activity A, instead of Activity B.
I can't disclose my code, so I am not attaching it. Sorry for the same.
If anybody can help me with this much of info, Please help me

code:

Activity B code snippet where the button is clicked :

```
 btnTakeVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {                
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(TakeAnotherPhoto.this,Recorder.class);

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,CreateAuctionScreen.ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
            }
        });
```

here is the onActivityResult

```
onActivityResult()
if(requestCode == CreateAuctionScreen.ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(CreateAuctionScreen.resetBitmap!=null)
                {                
                    CreateAuctionScreen.resetBitmap = null;
                }                
                Drawable dd;
                dd = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_pic_frame2x);
                CreateAuctionScreen.bmpSize = ((BitmapDrawable)dd).getBitmap();

                if(data != null){


                    Uri str = data.getData();
                    String path = getRealPathFromURI(str);
                    System.out.println(path);

                    Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                    CreateAuctionScreen.resetBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, CreateAuctionScreen.bmpSize.getWidth(), CreateAuctionScreen.bmpSize.getHeight(), true);

                    if(CreateAuctionScreen.resetBitmap != null){

                        if(CreateAuctionScreen.thumbList.size() < 20){
                            dpv.set_chkString("Video");
                            dpv.get_chkString();
                            CreateAuctionScreen.chkList.add(dpv);
                            CreateAuctionScreen.str_thumbList.add(path);
                            CreateAuctionScreen.thumbList.add(CreateAuctionScreen.resetBitmap);

                            hl.setAdapter(new GallaryImageAdapter(TakeAnotherPhoto.this,CreateAuctionScreen.thumbList.size(),ImageAdapter.CREAT_AUCTION_SCREEN, CreateAuctionScreen.thumbList));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(TakeAnotherPhoto.this, "You can add up to 20 pics & videos only", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Activity C (Custome Video Recorder )

```
public class Recorder extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    Button myButton;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean back;
    Timer timer;
    int counter = 1;
    String strPath;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        back = false;

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        setContentView(R.layout.recorde);
        initMediaRecorder();

        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(counter<=10)
                    counter++;
                //Android UI get Updated continouly
                else {
                    // If condition full filled the timer will stop here
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    mediaRecorder.release();
                    timer.cancel();
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath));

                    Recorder.this.finish();

                }
            } 
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);

        SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            timer.cancel();

            Intent i = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath));
//            i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath);
//            i.putExtra("isRecorder", true);
//            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }};

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prepareMediaRecorder();
        }
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            //Recorder.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();

            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }

        private void initMediaRecorder(){
            Random genraotr = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = genraotr.nextInt(n);            

            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
            CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/auction_video"+n+".mp4");
            strPath = "/sdcard/auction_video"+n+".mp4";
            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // Set max duration 10 sec.
            mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
        }

        private void prepareMediaRecorder(){
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Activity B launches Activty C?

Comment: You can disclose the code you are using to start the activity's with. I think the way you are doing that might be the problem. Also might be that your Activity B can not handle the 'back' navigation, and crashes, which explains the black screen and going back to A.

Comment: First, are you calling `finish()` in activity B? If not, then check the logcat output to see if activity B is terminating due to an exception. Even if there is no exception, the logcat should show when activity B is destroyed. Can you at least post the manifest showing how you declare activities A, B, and C?

Comment: Okay wait, I posting some code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Are you callng setResult() before you call finish() ?

Comment: @varevarao Yes I was calling setResult before finish(), but I have checked it calling finish(), then setResult(). But it has not helped me :(

Comment: Judging from the symptoms, it sounds like B is successfully receiving the data returned from C. The problem, I suspect, comes in the call to `createVideoThumbnail`. My guess is that this is trying to read from the sdcard and must do quite a bit of processing to create the thumbnail. This is happening on the event thread, which would explain the black screen. When it takes too long (or, perhaps more likely, fails in some way), the system kills off B and returns you to A. You can check most of this with the debugger. The logcat output would be most helpful here. Please post it.

Comment: Any errors (activity B crash?) in logcat? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in ActivityB.onActivityResult()? is it called? if not, does it have the right prototype? (@Override?)

Comment: Can you please tell, are the activities A, B and C in the same process and packages, or maybe A is in separate process that B?

Comment: I hv the same issue but little bit improvement in my case...My case is on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018752/regarding-android-activity   Plz guys solve this one...

Comment: Make a copy of your app, but with all the proprietary code stripped out.  Keep stripping out code until there's a bare minimum application that shows the problem.  If the problem goes away while you're stripping out code, then look at the last thing you removed and there's your problem.  If the problem doesn't go away, then show us what's left, along with the relevant logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a exception in Activity B. As everyone has suggested, debug OnActivityResult function in B. Check if you are retrieving the right path as printed by 'System.out.println(path)' in your function.