# Regarding Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm facing a big problem related to `Activity`. My scenario is as follows:

I starts activity A,clicked on a button then picked an image from the gallery then in `onActivityResult` I called `startActivity(B)`.

Now in my Activity B that image selected in A has been shown on `ListView` which is showing.

Now on click of a button I called `startActivityforResult(Recorder class)` opened a new activity which is a custom video recorder activity.

Now in activity Recorder on clicking stop button `mediaRecorder` stops, release and save video and then after `setResult` it goes to again activity B into `onActivityResult()`.
But here is the problem:

Two different cases I found here:

1. First one is when I declared my Recorder class as Landscape:

   Here on clicking stop button in Recorder class my screen goes black and after few seconds activity A starts.
2. Second  one is when I changed orientation of Recorder class to Portrait mode:

   Here on clicking stop button in Recorder class activity B starts (no black screen) but again after few seconds activity A starts.

One more thing which I observed here:

- I replaced `startActivityForResult()` with `startActivity()` in activity B and from Recorder Activity i again called `startActivity(B)` which shows activity B,
  but here something new happens after few seconds the same activity B starts again.
- I am sure this is just because of `MediaRecorder` as when I commented all media recorder code from my `Recorder` class then it was fine.

My Code of Recorder class is here:

```
public class Recorder extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        setContentView(R.layout.recorde);
        initMediaRecorder();

        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(counter<=10)
                    counter++;
                //Android UI get Updated continouly
                else {
                    // If condition full filled the timer will stop here
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    mediaRecorder.reset();
                    mediaRecorder.release();
                    timer.cancel();
                    Recorder.this.finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Recorder.this,B.class);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath));
                }
            } 
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);

        SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            timer.cancel();
            Recorder.this.finish();

            Intent i = new Intent(Recorder.this,B.class);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath));
        }};

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prepareMediaRecorder();
        }
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            //Recorder.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();

            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }

        private void initMediaRecorder(){
            Random genraotr = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = genraotr.nextInt(n);            

            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
            CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/my_video"+n+".mp4");
            strPath = "/sdcard/my_video"+n+".mp4";
            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // Set max duration 10 sec.
            mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
        }

        private void prepareMediaRecorder(){
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: try adding
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in your manifest file..

Comment: @KMI...Thanks but I have already mentioned this...

Comment: Do you get any information in DDMS? Maybe a stacktrace? To me it sounds like something is crashing Activity B and then your application is restarted and shows Activity A because it's the startup activity of the application. Also how does your Activity B look like?
Am I to understand that when you remove all the MediaRecorder code, the application is running fine or?

Comment: Yup, on removing the MediaRecorder code app is working fine...

Comment: Is there anything in the LogCat? If so please post it.

Comment: Which context are you using for the different activity launches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with your recorder class. Please try once using this code:

```
public class AndroidVideoCapture extends Activity{

    private Camera myCamera;
    private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    Button myButton;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean recording;  
    public static String strPath;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        recording = false;

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Get Camera for preview
        myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        if(myCamera == null){
            Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this, 
                    "Fail to get Camera", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
        FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(recording){
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                Intent i = new Intent(AndroidVideoCapture.this,TakeAnotherPhoto.class);
                i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);

                //Exit after saved
                finish();
            }else{

                //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
                releaseCamera();

                if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this, 
                            "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                mediaRecorder.start();
                recording = true;
                myButton.setText("STOP");
            }
        }};

    private Camera getCameraInstance(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){

        Random genraotr = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = genraotr.nextInt(n);    

        myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        myCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/auction_video"+n+".mp4");
        strPath = "/sdcard/auction_video"+n+".mp4";
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // Set max duration 10 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (myCamera != null){
            myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            myCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
                int height) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
              // preview surface does not exist
              return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
              // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
            }
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

        mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
        releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object               
        //Exit after saved
        finish();
    }

//  public void showMessage(String title, String message, final Context context){
//      try
//      {
//          AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
//          alt_bld.setTitle(title);
//          alt_bld.setMessage(message);
//          alt_bld.setCancelable(false);
//          alt_bld.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//
//              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//                  dialog.dismiss();
//                  
//                  Intent i = new Intent(AndroidVideoCapture.this,TakeAnotherPhoto.class);
//                  i.putExtra("returnedVideo", strPath);
//                  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
//              }
//          });
//          alt_bld.show();
//      }
//      catch (Exception e) {
//          // TODO: handle exception
//      }
//  }
}
```

and let me know if it works.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Gaurav It seems to be working...let me test my secenirio then i will let u know...

Comment: @Gaurav....Wow it is working great with little bit changes but they could be acceptable for my project...Thank U so Much....Congrats man..

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any code that would save and restore the Activity instance state. Android may destroy and recreate activities when it puts another activity on the top, also it restarts activities when you reorient the device. You seem having the problems exactly in these two cases.

Android then tries to resume activities but you need to assist by storing and resuming your state. Not much is restored by default, especially your own fields just get null values.

Implement [onSavedInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), putting into provided bundle (map) that may be important for your program to continue working. Then check if onCreate parameter savedInstanceState is not null and if so, restore that you think is important from this bundle. Also, implement [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Here is the code demonstrating the problem. It is a simple application that has one state variable of the type String. Start the program and try to reorient the device from portrait to landscape. Your message text will changed into something like "My state was null but now restored to 13c140ff7e6". Hence create() has been called the second time, the state field go null and must now be restored from the passed bundle. At the same time, the value in the static field most likely will be preserved (while in some cases also might go away), indicating that this is not a full cold restart of the application. This may explain how simple reorientation may crash the app that is unaware about such things. Starting another activity for result may cause the similar effect. The code also demonstrates how the problem should be solved.

```
package com.example.state;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String myState;

static String staticString;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView sv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String state = savedInstanceState.getString("myState");
        sv.setText("My state was " + myState + " but now restored to "
                + state+", static "+staticString);
        myState = state;
    } else {
        String state = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        sv.setText("My state: " + myState + ", cold start, now set to "+state);
        myState = state;
        staticString = state;
    }
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myState = savedInstanceState.getString("myState");
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("myState", myState);
}
}
```

with layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have added the example. It is tested on Google Galaxy Nexus Android 4.1.0. Just reorient the device from portrait to landscape to see the message about the gone/restored fields.